# EV printing makes unit test fail in INET/OmNET++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, omnet++, inet

I have a component I am testing:

```
namespace myproj {

class MyComp {
public:
  void doSome();
};

}

using namespace myproj;

void MyComp::doSome() {
  // Some code...
  // And in the end, for debugging purposes, I print in one of the streams
  EV_DEBUG << "Some debugging info" << endl;
}
```

#### My unit test

My test is an ordinary [OmNET++ Unit Test](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:testing:opptest) using the `opp_test` tool:

```
%description:
Tests my component

%includes:
#include "myproj/MyComp.h"

%global:

using namespace ::inet::test::myproj;

%activity:
MyCompTest test = MyCompTest();

test.testDoSome();

EV << ".\n";

%contains: stdout
my test out
```

Of course a class `MyCompTest` is using `MyComp` in order to run some logic which will eventually invoke `MyComp::doSome`.

Note that `testDoSome` will cause the string "my test out" to be printed.

#### The problem

The issue is that, because of that `EV_DEBUG` (same happens if I change it into `EV_INFO`, `EV_DETAIL` and all other `EV`s) in my original class (source/simulation code), the test output is poisoned and the final output is:

```
Some debugging info
my test out
```

Which makes the test fail. If I comment out `EV_DEBUG << ...` then the test is fine.

How to solve this problem? Do I really have to remove all `EV` printouts in my original code?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off printing by `EV_DEBUG` by adding these lines in `%activity` section:

```
#undef EV_DEBUG
#define EV_DEBUG  true ? EV : EV
```

Comment: does not work :( but the idea is that I can actually redirect this to a stream I create which outputs nothing. +1 because of the idea per se!

Comment: I think the whole idea might be wrong... Have you tried it? I have with a personal buffer and I realize there is a problem, the `undef` is not doing much as the simulation is compiled and then referenced in tests. Here we are using the precompiler, but the source code is already compiled!

Comment: No, I didn't try this solution. You are right, it will not work.